# Implode an multidimensional array by keys and values with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I want to join the array keys to a filepath with the value at the end as file itself (the array below is a "filetree")

Array (depth, size and keynames are dynamic):

```
[0] => bla.tif
[1] => quux.tif
[foo] => Array (
        [bar] => Array (
                [lorem] => Array (
                        [1] => ipsum.tif
                        [2] => doler.tif
                )
        )
)
[bar] => Array (
        [qux] => Array (
                [baz] => Array (
                        [1] => ipsum.tif
                        [2] => ufo.tif
                )
        )
)
```

This result would be fine:

```
[0] => bla.tif
[1] => quux.tif
[2] => foo/bar/lorem/ipsum.tif
[3] => foo/bar/lorem/doler.tif
[4] => bar/qux/baz/ipsum.tif
[5] => bar/qux/baz/ufo.tif
```

Maybe there is also a pure PHP solution for that. I tried it with `array_map` but the results weren't fine enough.

Comment: Try it with: recursiveiterator. http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Comment: With this structure, how would you handle the case where a directory name actually is a number?

Comment: @Yoshi, that case will not happen - all directory names are already named with letters. (This will not be changed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a recursive function to collapse this array. Here's an example of one:

```
function collapse($path, $collapse, &$result)
{
  foreach($collapse AS $key => $value)
  {
    if(is_array($value))
    {
      collapse($path . $key . "/", $value, $result);
      continue;
    }
    $result[] = $path . $value;
  }
}
```

And here's how to use:

```
$result = array();
$toCollapse = /* The multidimentional array */;
collapse("", $toCollapse, $result);
```

and `$result` would contain the "imploded" array